# React List Box optimized for thousands options to display

Tags: javascript, reactjs, listbox

I'm searching for a ListBox/DualListBox for React that can hold thousands of options without having delay or stucking problems on loading.

I found react-window https://react-window.now.sh/#/examples/list/fixed-size for simple list view but no way to do a selection...

...and react-windowed-select https://github.com/jacobworrel/react-windowed-select but there's no way to have a multiple select with this.

My goal is to have something like this wonderful DualListBox https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-dual-listbox but with the potential of a windowed list like the first link I mentioned.

If anyone could help it'll be very much appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I started using Autocomplete from MaterialUI and Virtualizing the list with multiple choice and checkboxes. It seems working very well.

https://material-ui.com/components/autocomplete/#autocomplete

https://material-ui.com/components/autocomplete/#checkboxes

https://material-ui.com/components/autocomplete/#virtualization

The list is virtualized thanks to react-window https://github.com/bvaughn/react-window

Hope this could help someone.